# Linq How to compute row count?

Tags: c#, linq

I am exploring a very messy SQL-Database via LINQPAD and I would like to get a list of all tables where at least one column is of type string.
Furthermore, I would like to compute the count of distinct values for each column mentioned above.

I have tried to jumble something together, but my LINQ is rusty and anyway I have used it mainly for LINQ to Objects...

```
foreach(var table in Mapping.GetTables())
{
(
from dm in table.RowType.DataMembers 
where dm.Type == typeof(string)
select new { dm.Name , dm.DbType , dm.Type , dm.MappedName, dm.IsPrimaryKey } 
)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compute the count of distinct values for each column"?

Comment: @dav_i Suppose you have two string columns, each 100 rows. The first column has only two possible outcoms "Yes" or "No" - so two distinct values. The second column contains random text - so there would be 100 distinct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think you were pretty much on the right track... the following seems to work (though is quite slow on the database I'm testing on):

```
from table in Mapping.GetTables()
from member in table.RowType.DataMembers
where member.Type == typeof(string)
let count = ExecuteQuery<int>(String.Format(
                "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT {0}) FROM {1}",
                member.Name,
                table.TableName)).FirstOrDefault()
select new { table.TableName, member.Name, count }
```

Comment: That looks good! My colleague has bombed the server at the moment, to feedback will take a while...
I am a little bit surprised that there seems to be no clean way to do the count in linq...

Comment: Well it's more that Linq-to-SQL has nothing (as far as I can tell), to be able to select data from a dynamically chosen table. LINQ itself isn't to blame.

Comment: well, thats a disappointment - I am doing exploratory work on hundreds of tables and dynamic selection would have been great..